# ZXing2.0 is not working in Android2.1

Tags: android, zxing

I need to add a `Barcode scanner` facility to  my app. I tried adding `core.jar` from ZXing 2.0 to my app and the tried to run it on Android 2.1. However, after installation, the "open" tab is in hide mode.

Why is the "open" tab not showing? Does ZXing 2.0 only a specific android version?

Comment: What is your source of the core.jar?

Comment: Download ZXing2.0 from thsite and using apache ant got the jar file..

Answer (score 2):

No. ZXing supported Android 1.5+ until version 1.7, and supports Android 2.1+ from 2.0. 
I have no idea what ""open" tab is in hide mode" means, but it has nothing to do with ZXing, and sounds like something in your own app.

Comment: I can't open app after install("open tab is in hide mode") in my phone.